# Apply pandas.to_numeric to selected subset of columns using loc in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

How to apply `pandas.to_numeric` to a subset of DataFrame selected using `.loc[]`? E.g. consider this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index([1, 2, 3]))
df['X'] = ['a', 'a', 'b']
df['Y'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['Z'] = [4, 5, 6]
df['Y'] = df['Y'].astype(object)
df['Z'] = df['Z'].astype(object)
df
    X   Y   Z
1   a   1   4
2   a   2   5
3   b   3   6
```

Notice that type of Y and Z columns is `object`.
I would like to apply `pandas.to_numeric` on columns Y and Z to change the data type to `int`. I tested 3 approaches:

```
df.loc[:, 'Y'] = df.loc[:, 'Y'].apply(pd.to_numeric) # (1) WORKS
df.loc[:, 'Z'] = df.loc[:, 'Z'].apply(pd.to_numeric) # (1) WORKS

df.loc[:, ['Y', 'Z']] = df.loc[:, ['Y', 'Z']].apply(pd.to_numeric) # (2) DOESN'T WORK

df.loc[:, 'Y':'Z'] = df.loc[:, 'Y':'Z'].apply(pd.to_numeric) # (3) DOESN'T WORK
```

Approaches (3) and (4) doesn't work with `pd.to_numeric`, but work with other functions, e.g.

```
df.loc[:, 'Y':'Z'] = df.loc[:, 'Y':'Z'].apply(lambda x: x*0)
```

correctly sets Y and Z columns to zero. Can someone explain why it does not work with `pandas.to_numeric`?

**EDIT**

Finally, it turns out that this behavior is intended, as there is a difference between `.loc[:, ...]` and `[]`. According to the documentation:

> Note: When trying to convert a subset of columns to a specified type using `astype()` and `loc()`, upcasting occurs. `loc()` tries to fit in what we are assigning to the current dtypes, while `[]` will overwrite them taking the dtype from the right hand side.

Therefore the type should be changed using `[]` as suggested in the answer of jezrael. More info in the [documentation](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/basics.html#astype).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like bugs.

For me working:

```
df[['Y', 'Z']] = df[['Y', 'Z']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
print (df.dtypes)
X    object
Y     int64
Z     int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: Super, it was good idea. I am really curious if it is bug or not, also if will be repaired in next version of pandas.